# Flimsy bound of maximal independent set

Tags: graph-theory

Problem:

For graph $F$, let $\alpha(F)$ denote the maximal size of $F$'s independent vertices set.

$G$ is a connected simple graph such that $\alpha(G)=a$, and for any edge $e$ of $G$, $\alpha(G-e)=a+1$, where $G-e=(V(G), E(G)-e)$. Show that $a\leqslant \frac{1}{2}|V(G)|$.

Source: own.

Attempt:

I thought of induction on $a$, but met with some obstruction (can't transfer to the lower situation). Then I thought of induction on a stronger conclusion, like:

> $G$ is a connected simple graph such that for any vertex $v\in G$, there is an independent set of $G$ of size $a$ that contains $v$, and $a$ can't be larger. For any edge $e$ of $G$, there is an independent set of $G-e$ of size $a+1$ that contains both vertices of $e$. Then prove that $a\leqslant \frac{1}{2}|V(G)|$.

But it becomes too puzzling and I can't ensure if it's a correct one. Please help. (I hope there is a solution without induction.)

Comment: Could you clarify if the this is a problem, or a conjecture on your part (the non-highlighted question)?

Comment: @AlexR. The non-highlighted part is a problem, definitly true.

Comment: Excluding complete graphs, are there any even vertex graphs which satisfy the properties of connectedness and additional independent vertices on any edge's deletion? I can only seem to find that cycles satisfy these properties, and only for graphs with odd vertex count.

Comment: @LarryB. Yes, there are. For instance, a graph of 8 vertex forms a cycle, we label them 1, 2, ..., 8 clockwise, and add (1, 5) and (2, 6). The original $a=3$, and after any edge deletion it becomes 4.

Comment: OP, Did you find a solution? I'm also interested in this.

Comment: @Rchn I'm afraid not.

Comment: I have been able to verify the first conjecture for all graphs up to order 10. There are $1,2,2,5,10,31,113$ graphs of order $4,5,6,7,8,9,10$, respectively, which satisfy the property that deleting any edge increases the graph's $\alpha$ by one. All of them satisfy $\alpha < \frac{1}{2}|V(G)|$ (strict inequality). I used nauty's geng to generate graphs, and a python's networkx and igraph library to read graph6 and repeatedly remove edges and calculate $\alpha$.

Comment: I would like to add a conjecture. For every odd-order, there is exactly one graph with the independence property having $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}(|V(G)| - 1)$, and it is the cycle graph. I haven't found any invariant properties among maximal $\alpha$ graphs with an even order. There are $1, 1, 3,6$ graphs of maximal $\alpha$ in graphs of order $4,6,8,10$ respectively.